# How to get child value from firebase realtime database relevant to unique uid key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have unique uid key, then how to get child element relevant with the key and assign it to variables using javascript.

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation about how to read data out of Realtime Database?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: I don't know the methodology how to get the child element relevant to well known unique uid key.

Comment: Please tell me you dont store Passwords as plain text

Comment: Can you share your existing code?